# Parametrization involving a quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric, parametrization

I need to parametrize $x^2-xz+1=0$ with $z$ being a parameter.

Now I've got a conceptual question about it: since if I had solved this for $x$, I'd get two solutions, then would the parametrization have two equations as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the quadratic equation we obtain

$$x=\frac{z\pm \sqrt{z^2-4}}{2}$$

therefore we have the following three cases

- for $z^2-4>0$ two real solutions $\implies$ two equations
- for $z^2-4=0$ one real solution  $\implies$ one equation $x=\frac z 2$
- for $z^2-4<0$ no real solutions  $\implies$ no equation

Answer (score 1):

Solve for $z$ if $x$ is given:
$$z = \frac{1 + x^2}{x}$$

Solve for $x$ if $z$ is given:
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{z\pm\sqrt{z^2-4}}{2}$$

Answer (score -1):

We know that $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has got two solution:
$$ \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
You have got: $a= 1, b=-z, c=1$ so we can replace in the formula:
$$\frac{z\pm\sqrt{z^2-4}}{2}$$
and that's your parametric formula $